# What does ROM Manager consume so much internal storage for

Tags: internal-storage, rom-manager

My Nexus S is running out of internal storage. I looked at the space consumed by individual apps in Titanium Backup. ROM Manager is consuming over 200Mb internal storage for "data". That is pretty much from 1Gb of storage. Is there any way to reduce the space consumed by it?

Comment: Have you at some point downloaded a ROM through ROM Manager, or made a backup of your phone through it? That 200Mb is about the size a ROM usually is.

Comment: @SaintWacko I have done both multiple times, but that is really not the case, as they go to the sd-card. I was able to find a xda post related to this. I think it is about somebody accidentally putting a rom as a icon in the rom list, so as you browse it, it starts downloading the rom instead. I will leave it as an answer later on when I find the post again

Comment: Oh, you mean *that* internal storage. Sorry, I thought you meant the internal SD. Didn't make the connection with it being 1Gb. Also, that's somewhat worrying that ROM Manager allows something like that to happen.

Comment: @SaintWacko I thought the same about the ROM Manager. I don't think the maker ever excepted the "thumbnail" to be anything else than a thumbnail. I don't know how long it was there, and it may be fixed already. EDIT: Actually just recently upgraded to cm10, and wiped the phone, so it IS pretty new

Comment: You'd think they'd put some simple constraints on what could be set as the icon. How is CM10 running? Is it at daily driver level? I'd like to flash my cappy up to it, but I need to be sure it's reliable.

Comment: @SaintWacko It might be hard to find out what a file is without downloading a part of it. There could of course be at least a size constraint. CM10 is running very nicely. I have a nexus device, so there are not that many hardware issues to begin with

Comment: That's exactly what I meant. A size constraint, and an extension constraint. I'll have to flash CM10 later today. I love JB on my N7, and I've been looking forward to getting it on my phone.

Answer (score 1):

This behaviour of ROM Manager was not intended, and according to the maker of the app, it has been fixed now.

The reason for this is the downloading of ROM icons when browsing the ROMs list. Somebody had posted a ROM as the icon causing it to be downloded in the background. I just ended up deleting the big file with Root Explorer. I don't know if I should have, or whether it broke anything, but I really needed the space.

[The article on XDA, where this was discussed](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1598509)